# URLDecode с символами % внутри самого текста

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! есть у меня, к примеру, вот такая строка 
    butter%2010%

что означает, что в состав входит 10 процентов масла.
И вот такое вот недозакодированное безобразие приходит мне от сервера. 
Подскажите, как это лучше перекодировать в нормальный вид для отображения.
URLDecode ругается на второй процент, после которого нету кода символа...

Comment: можно сделать хак - если последний символ процент, то добавить "25"

Comment: он не обязательно последний. после него может идти продолжение состава продукта

Comment: видимо придется писать свой кастомный декодер. Согласно [спецификации](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1630.txt), читаем (8 страница):

> Sequences which start with a percent sign but are not followed by two hexadecimal characters are reserved for future extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил криво, но так, как считаю, что это сервер мне криво отдает данные, то позволил себе сделать так.
А именно перед вызовом `URLDecode` ищу все %, после которых не стоит цифра или буква, и добавляю после них 25.

Comment: буквы то лучше проверять на диапазон a-fA-F, да и следующий символ нужно проверять.